# Including full log error message in alert notification using Loki + Grafana

Tags: grafana, alerts, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts

guys! I searched the entire Internet to find the answer to the following question:
How to include full log error message in alert notification using Loki as Datasource in Grafana.
For example, I have the following query:

count_over_time({app=“some-application”} |= ERROR [1s])

And I want if the last value of this request is more than zero, send a notification including the FULL log on which the alert was triggered
(example:
ERROR 1 — [ctor-http-nio-2] c.c.m.d.e.a.s.MarketDataEventSender : Error market data event sender [error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@361a6caf] )

And unfortunately, I didn’t find anything about this. Please, help me. Where I can find a step-by-step guide or some documentation about this, or you can write now how to do it.
It is not necessary to us Loki. In general, the task is:
How to set up an alert for a specific part of the application log and send the full log in notification. Maybe a different tool, not Loki, is suitable for my purposes.
I would be very grateful for a detailed answer. Thank you in advance!

I tried connect Loki to Grafana, creating alert. Tried some templates, but nothing work